# How to get users to log in and out of OmniChannel everyday?

Tags: omnichannel

We just recently implemented OmniChannel for our Service Cloud group and are having some adoption difficulties. Specifically with reminding users to log in and out of the tool when they start/end their shifts. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue? We find that cases are being routed to people logged in but not actually in the office, or the users completely forget to log in when they start in the morning.

Comment: Do you have a session time-out length set for your users? Perhaps you could tie it into that? If they're logged out due to their session having expired, it would seem there would be a related way to auto-log them out of OmniChannel.